# Minizinc: Initialize each row of 2d array with 1d array

Tags: multidimensional-array, minizinc

I would like to split the initialization of a large input array into smaller
chunks (just for readability). I tried this:

```
array[1..3,1..2] of int: arr;

% This works:
% arr = array2d(1..3,1..2, [0,0,2,2,3,3]);

% But this not:
arr[1] = [0,0]; 
arr[2] = [2,2]; 
arr[3] = [3,3]; 

constraint true;
solve satisfy;
```

When I run this code I get a syntax error:

```
arr[1] = [0,0]; 
   ^
Error: syntax error, unexpected =, expecting ':'
```

Is this not supported by `Minizinc` or did I miss something else?

(There was a somewhat related question [initialize-only-certain-elements-of-array-in-dzn-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47564111/initialize-only-certain-elements-of-array-in-dzn-file), but with no answer to my specific problem.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MiniZinc currently does not allow this for two reasons:

1. The assignment without an array is special initialisation syntax that can only be used for an identifier. Array access isn't allowed at the left side of this format. (The main reason for this is that the compiler needs a guarantee that all values are known, which is harder to check when the values are split between statements)
2. The current release of MiniZinc does not support array slices. This means that `arr[1]` is an invalid access to the array. On the development branch of the compiler there are array slices, but they are accessed as `arr[1,..]`.

My proposed solution would be to format the 2d-array in a 2d way, which should increase the readability. MiniZinc has a special formatting for 2d-array literals:

```
arr = [|
  0,0|
  2,2|
  3,3|
|];
```

**UPDATE**: Array slices are now fully supported in MiniZinc. However, assignment items still only allow the usage of identifiers.